# Should reputation be in human readable format on question revisions page?

Tags: bug, reputation

For example on this page https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66438616/revisions, Jon Skeet's reputation is displayed literally as `1243063`. Should it be in a short form as `1.2m` as it is on the question page [DateTimeOffset: TZ Offset is reset to +00:00 when fetching data from LiteDb collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66438532/72178)? I don't know whether it is a regression but anyway it looks a bit unreadable to me.

Comment: No, this is new. If you edit your post it will show up as the raw number. Intended feature I think.